# Loading a safetensor file in transformers

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have downloaded this [model](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/vicuna-13B-1.1-GPTQ-4bit-128g) from huggingface. I am trying to load this model in transformers so I can do inferencing:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("path_to/TheBloke/vicuna-13B-1.1-GPTQ-4bit-128g")

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("path_to/TheBloke/vicuna-13B-1.1-GPTQ-4bit-128g")
```

But i get the error saying that it expects a .bin or .h5 or .ckpt files but the above has only .safetensors or .pt files

How do i load the model?

Comment: trying the same. did you got it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

you need to tell it to look for the safetensors

```
AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    <path>,
    use_safetensors=True,
    <rest_of_args>
)
```

This assumes you have the safetensors weights map in the same folder ofc

```
model.safetensors.index.json
```

Comment: whats model.safetensors.index.json?

Comment: It has the weights map based on the safetensors-formatted chunks, exp in https://huggingface.co/HuggingFaceH4/starchat-beta/tree/main you can find both `model.safetensors.index.json` and `pytorch_model.bin.index.json`

Comment: But it seems that many repos don't have that safeensors.index.json.  EG https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/wizard-vicuna-13B-GPTQ/tree/main

Comment: GGML models don't have data in safetensor format. They don't _need_ it either, since they're already using a format without pickle's security problems.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* safetensors when you're using GPTQ content -- it's an alternative to pytorch's default (unsafe) "pickle" format.

GPTQ is already not using the unsafe pickle format, so safetensors are irrelevant and unnecessary (and consequently, safetensor-format files are not included in GPTQ repositories).

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be using safetensors when relevant - they're more secure and efficient than the alternatives (pt and bin). First confirm you have `safetensors` installed:

```py
import importlib.util
print(importlib.util.find_spec("safetensors") is not None)
```

Otherwise install it:

```bash
!pip install safetensors
```

If errors persist, try:

```py
!pip install 'transformers[torch]'
```

Things should work after resolving any dependency issues and restarting your kernel to reload modules. For reference, I was able to load a fine-tuned `distilroberta-base` and its corresponding `model.safetensors` file with the following:

```bash
!pip install accelerate==0.24.1
!pip install huggingface-hub==0.17.3 
!pip install safetensors==0.4.0 
!pip install tokenizers==0.14.1 
!pip install transformers==4.35.0
```

```py
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(<model_path>)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(<tokenizer_path>)
```